# Can we use Powershell in SharePoint server 2007 platform

Tags: 2007, powershell

I want to use the Powershell capabilities for SharePoint Server 2007. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can enable PowerShell

http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2013/01/22/running-powershell-on-moss-2007.aspx

PowerShell by default comes with Windows Server 2008, however it doesn’t come with Windows Server 2003 and my guess is that if you’re still running SharePoint 2007 you’re probably still running Server 2003. If you are among this group, all you need to do is install the hotfix ([KB926139](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926139)) on one of your web servers. If you’re running Server 2008, you’re ready to go.

http://blog.metrostarsystems.com/2011/04/20/leveraging-sharepoint-2007-through-windows-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

You won't have the luxury of the commandlets like `*-SP*`, but all of the managed code libraries will be at your disposal by means of reflection: `[reflection.assembly]::load*` methods will come handy.

Comment: Also please note that, we are loading only the SP2007 Sharepoint dll. Make sure you are using only those objects and methods avaialble in SP2007 SharePoint object Modal/